# How to fetch a row in an sqlite database in qt using cpp

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt

How can I access a single row in sqlite database and return the data in a list. I have tried this

```
QList<QVariant> DBManager::getUserData(QString usrNam, QString psswrd)
{
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare("SELECT First_Name, Last_Name, Email, Username, Password"
                  " FROM Users WHERE Username = :usrNam AND Password = :psswrd");
    query.bindValue(":usrNam", usrNam);
    query.bindValue(":psswrd", psswrd);
    query.exec();

    QSqlRecord rec = query.record();
    QList<QVariant> list;
    int idCol = rec.indexOf("First_Name");

    if(idCol == -1){
        qDebug() << "Db is empty";
    }else{
        while(query.next()){
            list.append(query.value(idCol));
            list.append(query.value("Last_Name"));
            list.append(query.value("Email"));
            list.append(query.value("Username"));
            list.append(query.value("Password"));
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

But the program crashes. Do not fully understand the use of a record here got it from the documentation. I do know that it provides details about the fields but I want the data in the fields of a particular row.

please help
thank you

Comment: *> But the program crashes.* is not very helpful. Did you try to run it through the debugger? Where exactly is the program crashing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access a single row, you don't need to use `QSqlRecord`. Just use `QSqlQuery::first` instead. Example:

```
QList<QVariant> DBManager::getUserData(QString usrNam, QString psswrd)
{
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare("SELECT First_Name, Last_Name, Email, Username, Password"
                  " FROM Users WHERE Username = :usrNam AND Password = :psswrd");
    query.bindValue(":usrNam", usrNam);
    query.bindValue(":psswrd", psswrd);

    QList<QVariant> list;

    if (!query.exec()) {
        qDebug() << "Query failed!";
    } else {
        if (query.first()) { // get the first record in the result,
            list.append(query.value("First_Name"));
            list.append(query.value("Last_Name"));
            list.append(query.value("Email"));
            list.append(query.value("Username"));
            list.append(query.value("Password"));
        } else {
            qDebug () << "Data not found";
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

Though, I would recommend using a data structure for `Users` instead of using `QVariant`. Something like:

```
struct User {
    QString firstName;
    QString lastName;
    QString email;
    //...
};
```

And then use a `QVector`(instead of `QList`) of type `User`:

```
QVector<User> list;
```

`QVector` store its data in contiguous memory, hence it is faster than using a `QList`.

Comment: Thanks for the Qvector suggestion. Implemented the solution you suggested and "Data not found" was returned but there database has data. Ran query.isActive() and query.isSelect() and got true in both cases.

Comment: try running the exact same query directly on the database(use sqlitestudio). Your parameters must have incorrect values.

Comment: It runs!!!!!! You're right I was using wrong parameters. The error was in testing the whole database manager class. I tested deletion before i could retrieve the data, so by the time getUserData(...) is called, the user no longer exists. A logical error on my part :(. Thanks